# CSS issues on site when browser window is a specific size

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a new website design and I'm having an issue with it. The site is http://www.paulietheboss.com/ - I'm only really focused on the homepage right now till I get this problem sorted out.

I'm trying to make the theme fully responsive, however if you resize the browser window and it gets between ~1027px and ~1065px wide a scrollbar appears at the bottom and part of the right hand side of the site gets cut off - try it and you'll see what I mean - any ideas?

(The width values I listed are in chrome, but the same seems to happen in other browsers at slightly different sizes)

A similar issue happens viewing on an ipad3 in landscape, but I believe it is related somehow.

Comment: Your class `.wrap` within `.inner` has a fixed width of `1060px` in your `max-width:1200px` media query. This is still applied at 1027 hence the scrollbar.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand just like that i want to marry you. THANKYOU.

Comment: hehe easy tiger ;-) glad you got it sorted